Custom Razor tag helper not applying to all tags, nor setting attribute value
Edit: This is working now.  Unfortunately, I didn't really do anything other than also make the tag helper applicable to <style> tags.  If you're having this same problem... godspeed.
I'm running an ASP.NET Core 8 MVC app with Razor views. I've written a custom ScriptTagHelper to add a "nonce" attribute to all my script tags.
It looks like this:
[HtmlTargetElement("script")]
public class ScriptTagHelper(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor) : TagHelper
{
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;

    public override void Process(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output)
    {
        var httpContext = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext;

        // This is set in Program.cs
        if (httpContext?.Items["CSP-Nonce"] is string nonce)
        {
            output.Attributes.SetAttribute("foo", "bar");
            output.Attributes.SetAttribute("nonce", "blah" /*new HtmlString(nonce)*/);
        }
    }
}

What I'm seeing is the "foo" and "nonce" attributes being added to all script tags but only the "foo" attribute gets a value.  The "nonce" attribute is just the attribute - no value.
Inline script tags don't receive either attribute. Edit: This was because the inline scripts I was checking were from a partial  that had a different _ViewImports applying to them.
So what I'm seeing is this:
<script src="https://url.com" foo="bar" nonce></script>
<script type="text/javascript">...</script>

I've put a breakpoint on the second SetAttribute call and it's being called for all the script tags I have on the page, it's just stubbornly refusing to set the value (and match inline tags).
Any advice?
